# How to write an expression over a data type and print it out in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am having to write an expression to construct a Poly representation of the polynomial x^3 + x + 1.

My algebraic data type Poly, which I wrote is:

```
data Poly = Lit Integer |
            Var |
            Add Poly Poly |
            Mul Poly Poly
```

The expression I can think of is this, but how can I be able to print out the result using print()?:

```
expr::Poly->Poly
expr = Add (Lit 1) $ Add (Var) $ Mul (Var) $ Mul Var Var
```

Also, I'd like to write a function like this:

```
showPoly::Poly->String
showPoly (Lit x)   = show x
showPoly (Var)     = "x"
showPoly (Add x y) = (show x) ++ " + " ++ (show y)
showPoly (Mul x y) = (show x) ++ "*" ++ (show y)
```

to enable the passing of a Poly expression and then converting it to a String. However, the above work tells me that I have no instance for (show Poly), which I am not sure what it mean.

Comment: Your expr seems fine, it just has the wrong type signature.  It's just a plain `Poly`

Comment: From your description, this problem could be many things....  I would get clarification from the prof what the assignment it....

Comment: Thanks. If I change the type to just Poly, then I get another error which basically says that "No instance for (Show Poly) arising from a use of `print'". That's because I am calling main = do print(expr), but I guess there's nothing to print. Is there a way to somehow print x^3 + x + 1?

Comment: You need to define an instance of `Show` for `Poly`. You can create it automatically by adding `deriving Show` right after your data declaration, but the output will not be what you want (try it). If you want a nice printout like `x^3 + x + 1` you need to do some more work (not enough place on this margin to describe it).

Comment: Do you mind adding it as an answer? I just edited the question to accomodate for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `expr` has the wrong type. `expr :: Poly` would be correct. You could also ask GHCi about that type:

```
> :t Add (Lit 1) $ Add (Var) $ Mul (Var) $ Mul Var Var
Add (Lit 1) $ Add (Var) $ Mul (Var) $ Mul Var Var :: Poly
```

In order to use `print` or a similar function, the type needs to be an instance of `Show`, since

```
print :: Show a => a -> IO ()
```

One way to achieve this is to simply *derive* the `Show` instance automatically:

```
data Poly = .... deriving (Show)
```

However, this won't lead to your desired result `"x^3 + x + 1"`. You need to write the `Show` instance yourself, for example:

```
instance Show Poly where
    show (Add x y) = "(" ++ show x ++ ") * (" ++ show y ++ ")
    show (Mul x y) = "(" ++ show x ++ ") * (" ++ show y ++ ")
    show (Lit x)   = show x
    show (Var)     = "x"
```

Note that this still isn't what you're looking for:

```
> show expr
"(1) + ((x) + ((x) * ((x) * (x))))"
```

However, that information should enable you to create your own instance.

---

Another way to solve this problem is to implement the `showsPrec` method of the `Show` typeclass.  This function threads through a precedence so that you can choose when to apply parentheses, allowing you to print out an expression that looks more like `1 + x + x * x * x` instead of the simple example using `show` above.  The type of `showsPrec` is a little wonky, though, it looks like

```
showsPrec :: Show a => Int -> a -> ShowS
```

Where

```
type ShowS = String -> String
```

The `ShowS` type is just encoding a diff list, which allows more efficient construction of Strings through function composition rather than simple concatenation.  For this `Poly` type, you would want to implement it something like this:

```
instance Show Poly where
    showsPrec d poly = case poly of
        Lit i   -> shows i
        Var     -> showString "x"
        Add l r -> showParen (d > add_prec)
                 $ showsPrec add_prec l
                 . showString " + "
                 . showsPrec add_prec r
        Mul l r -> showParen (d > mul_prec)
                 $ showsPrec mul_prec l
                 . showString " * "
                 . showsPrec mul_prec r
        where
            -- infixl 6 +
            add_prec = 6
            -- infixl 7 *
            mul_prec = 7
```

The `d` parameter represents the precedence.  Each call we check if the precedence is greater than that of each operator, and if so it adds parentheses around that expression (`showParen` conditionally puts parentheses around a `ShowS`), and then it builds the left and right trees of the expression with the correct precedence.  The precedences of `6` and `7` come from asking GHCi `:i (+)` and `:i (*)`, which show the fixity (precedence) of each operator respectively.

With another instance we can use this to write very readable instances as well:

```
instance Num Poly where
    (+) = Add
    (*) = Mul
    negate = Mul (Lit (-1))
    fromInteger = Lit
    abs = undefined
    signum = undefined
```

Keep in mind that this isn't entirely well behaved due to the `undefined`s, but it allows us to write code like

```
x :: Poly
x = Var

expr1 :: Poly
expr1 = 1 + x + x * x * x

expr2 :: Poly
expr2 = 2 * (x + 3 * x)

expr3 :: Poly
expr3 = (4 + x) * (4 * (x + 2) * x + x * (x + x + 4))
```

And to test:

```
> :l poly.hs
> expr1
1 + x + x * x * x
> expr2
2 * (x + 3 * x)
> expr3
(4 * x) * (4 * (x + 2) * x + x * (x + x + 4))
```

Which is identical to how we defined it in source code.

Comment: Thanks. How should I call this instance of Show which I'm going to write myself?

Comment: @RumenHristov: What do you mean "call this instance"? There are no names for instances. Maybe you're not too familiar with typeclasses yet? In this case have a look at the [typeclasses chapter in LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses), which includes `Show` examples.

Comment: Shouldn't use `show` for this in the first place, better to derive `Show` and make your own function to output. Easier to debug actually writing the output function this way.

Comment: I would instead recommend using `showsPrec`, which lets you output a `String` with more sane parentheses and whatnot.  The `Text.Show` module has pretty decent documentation showing an example for a `Tree` type that can be pretty easily adapted to a `Poly` type.

Comment: @bheklilr: It's a community wiki answer, feel free to edit ;).

Comment: How can I write a function printPoly, which uses the interface declarations from instance to print out an expression. Basically a function printPoly that takes a Poly expression and prints it out as a string.